# How to animate items in list while scrolling in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I'd like to create a grid list view in Flutter with an effect similar to the presented below on the right. Tiles' movement is delayed proportionally to the velocity. Similar effect can be seen [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/6784720-Gallery-App-Interactions).

[image: animated lists examples]

I tried to modify `SliverGridDelegate` implementation to increase `mainAxisStride` value depending on the scroll velocity.

In my `CustomScrollView` I placed modified [`SliverGrid`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverGrid-class.html) (`SliverAnimatedGrid`) with custom delegate that I called `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndAnimation` which is based on [`SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount-class.html).

`SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCountAndAnimation` accepts  `ScrollController` and uses its velocity in `getLayout(SliverConstraints constraints)` function to increase `mainAxisStride` of the grid.

Current implementation:

```dart
  @override
  SliverGridLayout getLayout(SliverConstraints constraints) {
    assert(_debugAssertIsValid());
    final double usableCrossAxisExtent =
        constraints.crossAxisExtent - crossAxisSpacing * (crossAxisCount - 1);
    final double childCrossAxisExtent = usableCrossAxisExtent / crossAxisCount;
    final double childMainAxisExtent = childCrossAxisExtent / childAspectRatio;
    // Here accessing scroll controller velocity
    final velocity = (controller.position.activity.velocity / 100.0).clamp(0, 20);
    return SliverGridRegularTileLayout(
      crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
      mainAxisStride: childMainAxisExtent + mainAxisSpacing + velocity,
      crossAxisStride: childCrossAxisExtent + crossAxisSpacing,
      childMainAxisExtent: childMainAxisExtent,
      childCrossAxisExtent: childCrossAxisExtent,
      reverseCrossAxis: axisDirectionIsReversed(constraints.crossAxisDirection),
    );
  }
```

This unfortunately is laggy and has some bugs because `controller.position.activity` should not be accesses besides testing or in subclasses of scroll controller.

Full working example can be found here in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/orestesgaolin/31917e8c6626baaa924bebe96fd6fd45).

Do you have any ideas on how to efficiently implement this or similar effect?

Comment: Hey @Dominik, did you ever figure out how to implement this?

Comment: @MorganHunt unfortunately not :/